# Is Microsoft SQL Server the same as other SQL in terms of syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a new job that requires me to know Microsoft SQL Server.  I haven't dealt with SQL since college and even then my professor was really bad and i  didn't even have any actual software SQL experience... we just wrote everything on pencil and paper

So I'm trying to learn as much as I can on the internet but nothing is coming up "specifically" for Microsoft SQL.

If i go over the SQL tutorials on say W3schools, does the majority of the syntax still apply to Microsoft's version?  I'm kinda naive to this topic and I need to pick this up quick.  Any specific advice on how I can go about learning this would be very helpful and would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Rather than using W3Schools, find yourself a good guide to Transact-SQL, the variant of SQL that SQL Server uses. W3Schools is a bit of a jack-of-all-trades site, and tends to be looked down upon.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I used W3Schools a great deal when I was getting going with SQL Server, no complaints.

Comment: thanks for your guys opinions.  will look at both.  i guess i just wanted to make sure if say.. i did go to the W3schools site, that I wouldn't be learning the wrong syntax, that would suck lol

Comment: The use of W3Schools has been debated at length (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource); although its articles may work there may be better ways of performing the tasks mentioned.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book: Beginning SQL Joes 2 Pros

Comment: Another nice place to interactively learn standard SQL (so no T-SQL specifics): [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net).

Comment: Have any of our answers solved your problem ? If so, please accept one! :)

Comment: sorry Morris, i accepted you and thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be learning the wrong syntax on W3Schools, they both are quite similar but T-SQL may seen to be more "powerful" in some cases.

Apart from that, you may also want to look at [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365303.aspx) for the tutorial from Microsoft;

look at [TSql link](http://www.tsql.info/) for another T-SQL tutorial site;

look at [here on pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=t-sql)  for video tutorials (not free),

or [on this link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023704X)  this book would be a good starter guide for you.